# Create a Graphics Method in a Class?

Tags: c#, class, graphics

Okay, so I'm creating a class in C#. It works fine, so I'm adding more methods. This is meant to port some BASIC commands as methods into C#. I want to create a method that'll automatically do graphics without having to manually set up pens, points, graphics, etc. Just type in a command. The problem is that...well...it won't work. When I compile, it runs, but it throws an exception when I call the method (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`). I know what the exception is telling me, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's my current code:

```
    Graphics g;

    public void gpset(int x1, int y1, string colour1)
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromName(colour1));
        g.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x1 + 1, y1 + 1);
        myPen = new Pen(Color.White);
        g.DrawLine(myPen, x1 + 1, y1, x1 + 1, y1 + 1);
        myPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }

    public void gline(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string colour1)
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromName(colour1));
        g.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        myPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }

    public void gbox(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string colour1)
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromName(colour1));
        g.DrawRectangle(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        myPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Since this didn't work, I tried to do this instead of `Graphics g;`

```
    PaintEventArgs e;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics();
```

Now it simply won't compile. It says `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'SmileB.SmileB.e'`.

I've also tried doing:

```
    PaintEventArgs e;

    //Later in the code:
    method stuff here()
    {
        other stuff here;
        e.Graphics.<command>;
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work either. Help? Is this even possible to do? Also, I've run these methods directly inside of a forms application, and they work, so the methods themselves seem not to be the problem.

EDIT: Also, is there a better way to do the `gpset` method? It should just create one pixel of colour.

EDIT EDIT: Here's how I'm declaring the class:

```
    using SmileB;
    namespace Drawing_Test
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            SmileB.SmileB ptc = new SmileB.SmileB();

            //Down here is where I use the code
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you declaring SmileB?

Comment: Like you usually declare a class. ``using SmileB; /*Later on:*/ SmileB.SmileB ptc = new SmileB.SmileB();``

Comment: Show the code please...

Comment: Please show the real code not just fragments

Comment: What is SmileB please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Okay, I edited with how I'm declaring it. SmileB (Short for SmileBasic, the language I'm basing this class on) is the namespace and name for the class I'm creating.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `e` is never defined. Looks like you are trying to use the `PaintEventArgs` object, commonly named `e`, to access your `Grahpics` object. You need to overload `OnPaint` to get this event object. You can't simply make your own.

Also, the `Graphics` object is disposed after a paint event, you should not be holding on to it. Only use it locally within the scope of the `OnPaint` event.

**EDIT** You asked for me details. The point is, you shouldn't be making your own `PaintEventArgs`, nor your own `Graphics`. You should hook into `OnPaint` to get these objects.

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // some code to define x1, y1, colors, etc
    gpset(g, x1, y1, color1);
    gline(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, color1);
    gbox(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, color1);
  }

  public void gpset(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, string colour1)
  {
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromName(colour1));
    g.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x1 + 1, y1 + 1);
    myPen = new Pen(Color.White);
    g.DrawLine(myPen, x1 + 1, y1, x1 + 1, y1 + 1);
    myPen.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
  }

  public void gline(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string colour1)
  {
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromName(colour1));
    g.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    myPen.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
  }

  public void gbox(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string colour1)
  {
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromName(colour1));
    g.DrawRectangle(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    myPen.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
  }

}
```

If you need to do this from another object NOT DURING a paint event, please read about [Creating a Graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you are making this draw method from another object during a paint event, just pass the `Grahpics` you get from its `PaintEventArgs` to these methods.

Comment: Now I'm just getting a big red X on my form. :/ Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @ThePhillipParadox sounds like it is working then :) I'm not even being sarcastic. If you don't want a big red X, sounds like you need fix another problem with your code.